# CFArrayAppendValue crash when adding CGColorRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a TestFlight crash log from user with iPhone 4S iOS 7.0.4 Jailbreak.

[image]

Crashes on this line:

```
CFArrayAppendValue(colorArray, lighterColor);
```

Full method where the crash happens:

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color_ Height:(CGFloat)height_ Retina:(BOOL)retina_
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1.0f, height_), YES, retina_ ? 2.0f : 1.0f);
    CFMutableArrayRef colorArray = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 2, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    CGColorRef lighterColor = CGColorRetain([[color_ lighterColor] CGColor]);
    CGColorRef darkerColor = CGColorRetain([[color_ darkerColor] CGColor]);
    CFArrayAppendValue(colorArray, lighterColor);
    CFArrayAppendValue(colorArray, darkerColor);
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, colorArray, NULL);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), gradient, CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), CGPointMake(1.0f, height_), kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGColorRelease(lighterColor);
    CGColorRelease(darkerColor);
    return image;
}
```

I would love to know how to deal with this problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Verify that `lighterColor` is not NULL, before adding it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your crash is that the value passed in to CFArrayAppendValue is `NULL`. Or rather, something that is not expected by the retain callback. A valid `CGColorRef` will work fine with the retain callback.

Looking at the code you pasted above, the likely cause is `color_` being nil. This causes `lighterColor` to be nil and its `CGColor` member to be `NULL`

Add a nil check in this method or debug you application at an earlier point.

Comment: I added a line that check whether color_ is nil. If it is nil I use [UIColor whiteColor]. Still crashes!

Comment: In the same spot? That is highly unlikely. Can you verify that lighterColor is not NULL?